# Thomason’s homotopy colimit theorem for pseudo-functor

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Thomason’s homotopy colimit theorem

> R W Thomason, Homotopy colimits in the category of small categories,
>   Math. Proc. Camb. Phil. Soc. (1) 85 (1979)91-109

says that for a **functor** $F:I^{op}\to Cat$, the homotopy colimit and pseudo-colimit are the same. More precisely, there exists a natural homotopy equivalence
$$
hocolimt(N F)\to N(\int F),
$$
where $\int F$ is the Grothendieck construction (computes pseudo-colimit).

My question is, what if we consider a **pseudo-functor** $F: I^{op}\to Cat$.

Now the right hand side is still defined. For the left side, he says it is not defined. But if we compose $F$ with nerve, we obtain a pseudo-functor $F: I^{op}\to SSet$, which induces a functor $hoNF: I^{op}\to hoSSet$, then take colimit in $hoSSet$. Are the two sides homotopical equivalent?

Comment: The homotopy category is not cocomplete. It actually has very few colimits apart from coproducts.

Comment: @MaMing The Grothendieck construction is not a pseudocolimit, but rather a lax (or oplax, depending on taste) colimit.

Answer (score 2):

The most general result of this form that I know is from [0907.0930](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.0930): "Classifying spaces for braided monoidal categories and lax diagrams of bicategories" by Carrasco-Cegarra-Garzón.  They deal with lax diagrams of bicategories and include (at least) two useful things:

- A rectification functor from lax diagrams to strict diagrams.
- A Thomason theorem of the form you want.